# laravel withCount of linear nested relations in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relation

I have tables,

**ec_products** : id | brand_id (id from ec_brands) | store_id (id from mp_stores)

**ec_brands**: id

**mp_stores**: id

I am calculating total products belong to each brand and store using  relations and withCount of Laravel, Like,

Brand model,

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'brand_id')->where('is_variation', 0);
}
```

Stores model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'store_id')->where('is_variation', 0);
}
```

And in each model,

```
$data = $data->withCount(‘products’);
```

Now I introduced categories, One product belongs to multiple categories.

So used separate table to link category and product.

**ec_product_category_product**: id | category_id (from category table) | product_id (from our products table)

So final question I have, How to join all,

I want to **list** each of these (brand,store, category) and **count** products of each based on request parameters.

Like

if any brands selected, then count store and category related to that brand.

if stores selected, then count brands and category  related to that store.

if any category selected, then count store and brand  related to that category.

[structure of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XrfW.png)

Suggestion or solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should always start you Eloquent query with the Object you want to manipulate, here, it's Product and THEN constraint your query,

so in your controller :

```php
$product_count = Product::when($request->category_id, function($query) use ($request){
       $query->where('category_id', $request->category_id);
    })
[...] //do that for each of your constraints
->count();
```

if you want to do a search on the name of the category for example, use a whereHas :

```php
$product_count = Product::when($request->search, function($query) use ($request){
       $query->whereHas('category', function($query) use ($request){
             $query->where('name', 'like', "%$request->search%");
       });
    })
[...] //do that for each of your constraints
->count();
```

Comment: My query is to count the products comes under respective filter, as i have separate eloquent query to fetch real data. So looking for optimal solution which does not effect performance.

The page we are working on, ecommerce listing page, left side filters (count) and right side items list.

table structure [link] (https://pasteboard.co/K5YEge8F.png)

Comment: filter section screenshot is attached in main post. @MathieuFerre